# reactjs state not updating via redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I am trying to build a simple timer app using ReactJS and Redux and having a little problem with state in redux.

Here are the codes.

```
import React from "react";

var {connect} = require('react-redux');
var actions = require('actions');

export var TodoBtns = React.createClass({
    startTimer: function (todoTimer) {
        var {dispatch} = this.props;
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log(todoTimer);
            dispatch(actions.startTimer(todoTimer - 1));
        }, 1000);
    render: function () {
        var {todoTimer} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <a className="button" onClick={() => {
                    this.startTimer(todoTimer);
                }}>Start</a>
                <p>{todoTimer}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default connect(
    (state) => {
        return {
            todoTimer: state.todoTimer
        };
    }
)(TodoBtns);
```

On this page, I want the anchor tag to execute "startTimer" function which will decrement the value of "todoTimer" state by 1 and render it in the view to create a timer effect.

This is what the actions page looks like.

```
export var startTimer = (todoTimer) => {
    return {
        type: "START_TIMER",
        todoTimer
    };
};
```

This is what the reducers page looks like.

```
export var startTimerReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "START_TIMER":
            return action.todoTimer;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

And this is what the store configuration page looks like.

```
import * as redux from "redux";
import {startTimeReducer} from "reducers";

export var configure = (initialState = {}) => {
    var reducer = redux.combineReducers({
        todoTimer: startTimeReducer
    });

    var store = redux.createStore(reducer, initialState, redux.compose(
}
```

Everything else is working as I can see the "timerTodo" state being printed out in the console in every 1 second (executed by startTimer function). However, the value of todoTimer never changes even though I pass "todoTimer - 1" value to the startTimer action.

One thing that I find odd with this situation is that the "dispatch(actions.startTimer(todoTimer - 1));" does fire, but only once. So once the value of todoTimer state decrements by 1, it stops updating the todoTimer state while other codes inside the setInterval function like "console.log(todoTimer)" keeps running in every one second.

What can I do to decrement the value of todoTimer state in every one second?

Comment: Are you sure that `dispatch` is a prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have sended the same value each time. Therefore component renders only once.
For quick test try:

```
startTimer () {
    setInterval(() => {
       var {dispatch, todoTimer} = this.props;
        dispatch(startTimer(todoTimer - 1));
    }, 1000);
},
```

setInterval should get todoTimer value each time.

**[webpackbin DEMO](http://www.webpackbin.com/N1a2-t3DZ)**